# Bind to negative of a boolean property with KVO

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-bindings, key-value-observing

I am using KVO to watch a checkbox, and to enable or disable a details input area based on the checkbox's state.  (I.e. if the checkbox is checked, the details area is enabled, otherwise not)  Something like:

```
[self.detailInputArea bind:@"enabled" toObject:self withKeyPath:@"enabledCheckbox" options:nil];
```

My problem is that now I would like to change this to instead set `detailInputArea`'s `hidden` property, to show/hide the view depending on the state of the checkbox.  The problem is that this would require inverse logic.  In other words, when setting its `enabled,` true means the view is enabled (can accept input) while false means it can't.  However, with `hidden,` true means the view is hidden, and false otherwise.  Obviously this wouldn't work, as the view would hide itself when the checkbox is checked (its `enabled` property is true).

Is there any way I can change this binding to act based on the inverse of the property it's watching, and/or is there a better way of accomplishing what I am trying to do here?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, this is part of what the options dictionary is for. Key-value binding allows the bound value to be transformed before it is set, via an `NSValueTransformer`, and you can specify the transformer in the options for the binding.

The `NSValueTransformer` class provides [some default, named transformers](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSValueTransformer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001922-SW4). In this case, you'll be interested in `NSNegateBooleanTransformerName`.

Thus the binding you want will look like:

```
[self.detailInputArea bind:@"hidden" 
                  toObject:self 
               withKeyPath:@"enabledCheckbox" 
                   options:@{NSValueTransformerNameBindingOption : NSNegateBooleanTransformerName}];
```

Comment: Ugh, I HATE confusing things like `NSValueTransformerNameBindingOption ` with `NSValueTransformerBindingOption`.  It's far too often, that at such times I... want to go look... for my gun.

Answer (score 3):

Here's [Josh Caswell's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21245540/3939277) in **Swift 3**:

```swift
detailInputArea.bind(NSHiddenBinding,
                     to: self,
                     withKeyPath: #keyPath(enabledCheckbox),
                     options: [NSValueTransformerNameBindingOption: NSValueTransformerName.negateBooleanTransformerName])
```